# Google Chrome Console Error unexpected indentifier

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple captcha in javascript.

I think I have everything sorted out down to one error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier index.html:61

This is in the html.

`<div id="displayCaptcha"></div>`

This is the whole javascript code.

```
 <script>
    var path="images/";
    var extension=".gif";
    var displayCaptcha="";
    var validateCaptcha="";
    var randomNumber="";

  function displayCaptcha() // generate a randomNumber, 0-25
  { 
      var imgName = new Array();

    imgName[0]="a";
    imgName[1]="b";
    imgName[2]="c";
    imgName[3]="d";
    imgName[4]="e";
    imgName[5]="f";
    imgName[6]="g";
    imgName[7]="h";
    imgName[8]="i";
    imgName[9]="j";
    imgName[10]="k";
    imgName[11]="l";
    imgName[12]="m";
    imgName[13]="n";
    imgName[14]="o";
    imgName[15]="p";
    imgName[16]="q";
    imgName[17]="r";
    imgName[18]="s";
    imgName[19]="t";
    imgName[20]="u";
    imgName[21]="v";
    imgName[22]="w";
    imgName[23]="x";
    imgName[24]="y";
    imgName[25]="z";

    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        console.log();

    randomNumber = Math.floor ((Math.random())
    displayCaptcha+="<img src='"+path+imgName[randomNumber]+extension+"'/>";
    document.getElementById("displayCaptcha").innerHTML=displayCaptcha;
    validateCaptcha+=imgName[randomNumber];
            }
    }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use source `src` attribute for image.

```
displayCaptcha+="<img src='"+path+imgName[randomNumber]+extension+"'/>";
```

syntax error is in:

```
randomNumber = Math.floor ((Math.random()
```

write as

```
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random());
```

Comment: I did make the change, but it still gives me the same error. I have been looking at this for so many hours now trying to figure it out. Thank you for answering.

Comment: The code you paste in your question having no syntax error that seems to be caught in javascript. please show some more code

Comment: your syntax error is here: Math.floor ((Math.random()

Comment: Still did not fix that particular error, but did fix another.

Answer (score 0):

In line 61 ...modify the code as follows.You are missing the `src` attribute

```
displayCaptcha+="<img src='"+path+imgName[randomNumber]+extension+"'/>";
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I still get the same message after making the change.